# Am able to parse the first and last name, from full name, how do I parse the Middle Name?

Tags: t-sql

Am able to parse the first and last name, from full name, how do I parse the Middle Name? There are no titles used such as 'MR','MS','DR','FR', 'MRS','LRD','SIR', 'LORD','LADY','MISS','PROF so I think I can use the substring. The name format can be firstname middlename lastname, or firstname lastname, with the space in the middle.

```
UPDATE p
SET    p.LAST_NAME = c.LASTNAME --tested that join is correct, contact name is combined, will need to parse it out ***, need to reference inserted

       --Need FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME
       p.FIRST_NAME = SUBSTRING(c.CONTACT, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', c.CONTACT) - 1) AS FirstName,
       p.MIDDLE_NAME = --need middle name
       p.LAST_NAME = SUBSTRING(CONTACT, CHARINDEX(' ', CONTACT) + 1, len(CONTACT)) AS LastName

FROM   GMUnitTest.dbo.CONTACT1 c 
       JOIN PCUnitTest.dbo.PEOPLE p
         ON p.PEOPLE_ID = c.KEY4  
         WHERE c.Key1 = '31';
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data? Also what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: ah yes... this has been debated hundreds of times. What constitutes a middle name? what if they have two middle names like `Mary Ann Jennings Smith` or something similar? What if there is a JR or SR suffix? The point is, don't store them as Full Names. Unless you have some plain names, you are going to have errors. Different languages, different cultures... FN MN LN isn't standard everywhere. Even if you work out a statement that works... it isn't guaranteed to continue to work as new data is inserted into your tables.

Comment: Thanks, it's a 3rd party cms, I was shocked when I saw the name stored as one column. I ran queries to search for prefix and suffix and there' snot any

Comment: --sample data
ACCOUNTNO LASTNAME KEY1 KEY4 PEOPLE_ID FIRST_NAME MIDDLE_NAME LAST_NAME
B2022172153)J #6 Aar Vaughan, Arnie, 31-ATE 83801 83801 Arnie Ray Vaughan      
B2022168735*)]>4 Son Penny, Sonny, S 31-ATE 83811 83811 Sonny J Penny      
B3011151051*S)P]?Bry Perry, Bryann 31-ATE 86221 86221 Bryanna Gabrielle Gabrielle Perry
B2022369421$#L1@ Jac Vasseur, Jacky 31-ATE 88294 88294 Jacky M Vasseur

Comment: it looks like i need to search for the substring with a space before an after

Comment: I found something close, now I just have to morph that into the update statement
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(CONTACT,space1,space2 - space1 + 1) middlename
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CONTACT,
        CHARINDEX(' ',CONTACT) space1,
        LEN(CONTACT) - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(CONTACT)) space2,
        LEN(CONTACT) as totallength
    FROM GoldMineUnitTest.dbo.CONTACT1
)c
GO

middlename
 Penn
 Vaugha
 Vasseu
 Gabrielle
 Burto

Comment: Just a side note, i wouldn't look to update your table. I would just create a view.

Comment: This is a bridge for synchronizing two separate erp crm databases

Comment: So are you assuming that the name is always `FirstName <space> MiddleName <space> LastName` like the following example `John Ray Smith`

Comment: yes, i've ran queries to test it out, and the clerical procedure is to enter that format

Comment: p.FIRST_NAME = SUBSTRING(c.CONTACT, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', c.CONTACT) - 1) AS FirstName, -- line 1177
       p.MIDDLE_NAME = (SELECT SUBSTRING(CONTACT,space1,space2 - space1 + 1) middlename
      FROM
      (
       SELECT
        CONTACT,
        CHARINDEX(' ',CONTACT) space1,
        LEN(CONTACT) - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(CONTACT)) space2,
        LEN(CONTACT) as totallength
       FROM GoldMineUnitTest.dbo.CONTACT1
      )c) --need middle name
       p.LAST_NAME = SUBSTRING(CONTACT, CHARINDEX(' ', CONTACT) + 1, len(CONTACT)) AS LastName -line 1188

Comment: I think the query would work like this, but I get error Incorrect syntax near 'p' on line 1177 and 1188.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you said, that there **must** be a middle name, you can use something like this:

```
declare @table table (fullName varchar(256))
insert into @table values
('First Middle Last'),
('John Mary-Lou Smith'),
('Frank NMN Sanatra')

select
    CHARINDEX(' ',fullName,1)
    ,left(fullName,CHARINDEX(' ',fullName,1) - 1) as FirstName
    ,substring(fullName,CHARINDEX(' ',fullName,1) + 1,(len(fullName) - CHARINDEX(' ',fullName,1)) - charindex(' ',reverse(fullName),1)) as MiddleName
    ,right(fullName,charindex(' ',reverse(fullName),1)) as LastName
from
    @table
```